# When Jack Torrance is frozen, why is he looking up?

Tags: analysis, the-shining

The Shining (1980) uses a lot of symbolism referencing heaven and hell.  One example is the use of circular overhead chandeliers appearing like halos above characters' heads.

I'm wondering if there are any sources that say that when Jack Torrance is frozen at the end, he is looking upwards to symbolize the devil looking up at heaven?

[image]

Comment: Interesting theory.  I always assumed it was just because when people are frustrated, they tend to do that.  I never really applied the Heaven/Hell symbolism to it.  As for a definitive source, I don't recall any.

Comment: @JohnnyBones I've always loved that movie, and only started noticing the symbolism on the 3rd or 4th viewing.  My question about Jack's eyes only occurred to me a couple hours ago. To me, the expression on his face looks resentful, which would fit with the "devil looking at heaven" theory.

Answer (score 14):

Don't think there is one..

It is to make him look more sinister :)

If he was looking down he would look disappointed, if he looked straight ahead, he "might" look normal, but by looking up he looks like a psychopath.

Another note is the "Kubrick stare":

Kubrick used that effect to great ..effect.. to make his actors look mental. Apart from *The Shining*, it was used in *A Clockwork Orange* in the opening scene.

Comment: Brilliant!  [Kubrick Glare Super-cut](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFXuJaeT_J8)

Comment: I always thought his eyes looked awkwardly comedic (slightly crossed) given how hateful and evil he was. It didn’t seem to fit the tone. Looking straight into the camera would have been chilling.